# PHP ip2long function not giving current result

Tags: php, mysql, ip

The following code works fine on http://writecodeonline.com/php/
but unfortunately it cannot provide current output at my localhost.

$eip = '255.255.255.254';
echo $longeip = ip2long($eip);

Output should be displayed like this 
`4294967294` but it gives `2`

For `enter code here`IP 1.0.0.1 and i am getting current output `16777217`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because [`ip2long()`](http://php.net/ip2long) will return *integer* value which is **signed** in PHP, so available inteval is `[-1*2^31 .. 2^31-1]`. Thus, it will be `-2` because of binary representation.

If you want unsigned value, use

```
$longeip = sprintf('%u', ip2long($eip));
```

here `%u` specifies "unsigned integer" for [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf). Be aware that result will be *string* in this case.

Comment: @user3165155 different systems (64bit vs 32bit)